# Do we need the "directories" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we need the [directories](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directories) tag?

It seems very general and not all that applicable to the majority of 3D workflow questions.

Are there any pros to keeping this tag?
Should we wait for a while and see if it gets used in a useful way?

Comment: I agree it is rather vague and currently only has 2 borderline questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was going to remove it, but iklsr has told me to talk about any tag changes before I do anything. So I have not removed it yet. If you are in support of removing it also, then I will delete it.

Comment: Takes two to tango. As long as no one person is making any changes and the change is made public it's fine. I think it can be removed.

Comment: I've left a comment on the post where the tag was created, just in case the creator wants to put in a word or two.

Comment: I was inclined to remove them, but hesitated because of administration and discussion and so on. IMHO the tag should be removed.

Comment: I think it is useful, if people ask question about linking, saving, importing, exporting etc. Sometimes people doesn't know right syntax for directories in Python etc.

Comment: Maybe it should be just renamed...

Comment: @AdriansNetlis there are already tags for: linked-data, import, export, and file-format, so I do not see a need to rename it.

Answer (score -1):

I think it may eventualy be useful.  Although most people use the default install location of blender, that has no white spaces, someone will eventualy come along that will install to "Program Files", which has a white space and run into problems with a python script.

I've already seen a post where the person who gave a good answer with some code had no need for enclosing a piece of python code that accessed a file because his file path had no whitespace, the person using his code ended up stating that it didn't work.  He had blender in "Program Files" and that was why.  It may have been just yesterday that I saw it.

This directory tag would fit well in a situation like that and alow anyone else with the same issue the ability to find it quickly in a search as long as a moderator/editor ensures it is tagged.